# Is this equation correct?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph with n nodes on left side and m nodes on right side. So for example, in the below picture, I have **n=3** and **m=4**.

[image]

Now, I have come up with an equation to find all possible matches. The only condition for the match is, it should just have distinctive edges (or in other words, if there is an edge between **n1 -> m1** there can be no other edge as **n1 -> m2** or **n2 -> m1**).

The equation that I framed is,

[image]

So for the above picture, the total possible matches can be 36. Is my framed equation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is not correct (and does not result in 36 for $n=3, m=4$, but in 48).

Try the equation $\sum_{i=1}^ni!{n\choose i}{m\choose i}$ (for $n\leq m$).

The $i$-th term in the sum represents the number of matches with $i$ edges:
each choice of $i$ vertices from the $n$'s combines with each choice of $i$
vertices from the $m$'s and then there are $i!$ different ways to form a valid match.
(This formula does not allow a match with no edges).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do we need the condition (for n <= m). Is there any way I could generalize it?

Comment: With the usual convention that ${n\choose i}=0$ whenever $i>n$, you can even use $\infty$ as upper limit in the sum.

Comment: I like the min(n,m) in the summation. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Choosing $i$ vertices from each doesn't seem to be sufficient to count all possible matchings. This counting doesn't treat $\{(n_1, m_1), (n_2, m_2)\}$ and $\{(n_1, m_2),(n_2,m_1)\}$ as distinct matchings. $\sum_{i=1}^{\min(n,m)} i! \binom{n}{i} \binom{m}{i}$ would take care of this.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'll edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramesh: please take notice of the improvement. My first answer was incorrect. Sorry :(

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk, no problem. I figured that out :) Your initial equation pointed me to the right direction. Thanks for your help